# Work flow for authentication and API use with Twitter on OAuth

Tags: twitter, oauth, desktop-application

I'm a bit confused about all this OAuth bruhaha in the sense that all the examples I can find are for web applications and none of them for desktop applications.

I understand the Web application work flow, but that includes some redirections between the web app and twitter.

- How does one do this in an desktop application?
- How does the redirects work?
- Should I have to include a Web Browser object?
- Is there a way to go around this?
- Could anyone point me to resources instead of a full blown solution please?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this ? i am doing the same - building a desktop twitter app and having a NIGHTMARE! please post your solution or code if you did!

Comment: Unfortunately I got more questions than answers. I have like 3 to 4 ways of doing it. But all range from the User Annoying to the Devilish Programmer Hack. It's just workarounds for something that was not thought to be. ARGHHHH!!!!

Comment: Would you be able to help move this mental block i have then... I dont know what to do with the pin number?! I am diverting the user to a web browser control to sign in and then they click submit and it goes to the pin number...but i dont know what to do with the pin number, and i dont know how to get my application to know that the user has clicked submit so the form can shut itself! Any ideas?

Comment: I just want an access token please =[

Comment: @xoxo: The process of transforming a Request Token into a Auth Token I think you mastered. If you look at Twitter's response you will be redirected to the URL that contains the AUTH token. Just parse the response from Twitter to obtain that token. Then use verify_credentials to confirm that you have the correct AUTH and you can go ahead.
Another link that may help: http://chuckbeasley.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/using-oauth-for-delphi/

Comment: @xoxo: this link may also help you: http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/?p=681

Comment: But i dont get redirected to any page containing a token though,i get directed to the "...return to *app* and enter the following PIN to complete the process.." page, and the only thing i can find in that pages source is that oauth_pin. Im just not sure what im supposed to do with this pin. And also, how does my windows app know that this page has logged in and granted this pin from the web browser (i dont usually dabble in the web stuff!) And thanks for the link, i have looked at that before-but that again is a web page and not a desktop application like mine. This is getting so frustrating!

Comment: @xoxo: I haven't tried it yet myself. I'll have a go on Delphi/FreePascal and then I'll get back with some answers.

Comment: If i just let the user close down the browser after logging in and getting on that pin page and just assume that the token has been authenticated from the user doing this (and do nothing with the pin), and try and swap it for the access token, i get a 401 not authorised error, so i think i can assume i have to do something with that pin! Thanks so much for your help, im so stuck! unforntunatly not much online about twitter on the desktop!

Comment: Something I found online: 
"Request the access token and access token secret for this user. You must pass the PIN# (for desktop applications) or the ouath_verifier value, provided as a parameter to the oauth callback (for web applications) as $verifier."

Not sure i quite understand that...

Comment: Ok i solved it, i took the oauth_pin that comes back after the user has uuthorised the request and put it in the oAuth_verifier parameter that needs to go in the request access token URL. The reason this was so hard to get to the bottom of is because there is alot of flow charts online with details of all the parameter, but most fail to tell you about the oauth_verifer parameter, but I HAVE AN ACCESS TOKEN!! woop!

Comment: @xoxo: Man, that's great!! could you put that workflow into and answer  so I could unmark my answer as the one and give you the respect? Thanks

Comment: No thats ok, i cbb to rewrite it anyway! One last thing...So now i have my access token, im trying to call the update status URL. I built up my url and signature exaclty the same as all the other times, apart from this time im including 'status=' and the access token instead of request token, but im getting a 401 Unauthorized error...am i supposed to be including headers with a WebRequest, cos right now im using a web client with the status written in the url (after being UrlEncoded of course...). Its impossible to see whats causing this error in the url though, any ideas?

Comment: This is the URL im calling thats causing an error: /statuses/update.json?status=test+tweet+from+my+amazing+twitter+api&
oauth_consumer_key=F3uExqTi2erIWZ9w0FhxTw&
oauth_nonce=7113394&
oauth_timestamp=1249648847&
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&
oauth_version=1.0&
oauth_token=20080355-GVDRUn2gX4F5ENiMxheWmPKt6LTVSd7ysEYyI&
oauth_signature=fn4%2f98JA4pEV08LIPPASer5%2bPPM%3d

Comment: @xoxo: After obtaining the auth token, did you make a call to verify_credentials before actually doing any calls to whatever service?

Comment: no i called the request access token url and sent in the oauth_verifier which was the pin number. once the user was directed to the pin number page, i just stripped it out of the source and instructed the user to close down the browser! What an arse ache!

Comment: Don't be to hard mate. Sometimes the obvious is the hardest to find ;)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which language you're using, but the .NET library for Twitter called Tweetsharp has a post on using Tweetsharp from a desktop app and authenticating via OAuth. See http://tweetsharp.com/?p=68. If you're not using .NET then perhaps it will inspire something you can do?

Basically, what tweetsharp does is launch the browser to the authentication URL and then waits for the user to return. I don't know of any way to do this other than something like that (Or include a WebBrowser control of some kind to launch the authentication URL in your own window).

Comment: Thanks mate, but that still involves going out of my way and wait for some external app. I need to contain it all in my App. It makes sense to have the login and password in your desktop app, hell, tell me of one that doesn't have...  
That really does not solve my problem, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. However, for OAuth in a desktop app, there is no other option. The whole point of OAuth is to *not* have your app ask for credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward solution, implemented as a set of PHP scripts for running from the command line. Well documented and explained, with a helpful 'verbose' option for debugging.

http://nullinfo.wordpress.com/oauth-twitter/

Answer (score 0):

After some poking around and asking some questions about this subject to some other programmers, it looks like it's still an ongoing discussion, with no visible light at the end of the tunnel.

But for people interested on the ongoing discussion, here's the best link to have:
[OAuth Desktop Discussion](http://twitter.pbworks.com/oauth-desktop-discussion)

Comment: After my "conversation" with xoxo it looks like a possible answer can be better than mine. Will hold for xoxo to get some stuff up.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few desktop apps get around this by effectively embedding a browser into their program, so they can just open the in-app browser window to let you do the login and authorisation.  This strikes me as a bit of a cheat or defeat of purpose because you still end up typing your ID and password inside the application anyway.

One possibility I was thinking of was, your desktop application could embed a mini HTTP server inside it.  So then it launches the default browser to perform the authorisation, with a callback URL something like http://127.0.0.1:8765/oauthorized and then just listen for it.

Would that work?

Not sure what you would do for console applications... spawn a copy of [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/)?

Comment: The HTTP server could work. I'll have to look into the localhost issue that aroused earlier just to confirm that it's still possible. Thanks for that suggestion, looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include a WebBrowser control in your app.  Put it in a panel or a separate form that you'll Form.ShowDialog().
2. Create a callback for the browser's successful posting of OAuth and one for a rejection.  Don't forget to check for a FailWhale.
3. In the callback, you close the panel or form and store the token.

Here's a nice overview with sample code and everything: http://tweetsharp.com/2009/04/how-to-authenticate-a-desktop-application-with-oauth/

Comment: The link you present is now giving me a 404. Is it the case that the Twitter API is now closed and it doesn't apply anymore?